# Returning false does not take effect in submit method of a form

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-events

Returning false does not  take effect in submit method of a form.

The method like this:

```
function success() {
    //some validation logic
    $.ajax(); // ajax call
    return false;
}
```

I have written the event method in `<input>` tag:

```
<input type="submit" id="export" value="${appResources.report_common_label_generateReport}" onclick="return runExport();" />
```

Who can tell me the reason? Why doesn't it work?
Much appreciated your help.

Comment: Can you show the HTML of your `<form>` tag?

Comment: can you give the detail of your HTML where you are calling success() method.

Comment: I have written the event method in <input> tag

Comment: <input type="submit" id="export" value="${appResources.report_common_label_generateReport}"
          onclick="return runExport();" />

Comment: Update the `<form>` tag's `onsubmit` event with the `return false;` value, or even better, give the main action! :)

Answer (score 0):

The "onsubmit" method of your form must return false in order to stop submission, what you are showing is a return from some other function.

Answer (score 0):

In that case, you need to correct two things. Update the `<form>` tag's `onsubmit` event with the `return false;` value, or even better, give the main action:

A. The `form` tag:

```
<form method="" action="" onsubmit="runExport(); return false;">
```

B. The `input` tag:

```
<input type="submit" id="export" value="${appResources.report_common_label_generateReport}" onclick="return runExport();" />
```

#### Why are we using a `return false;`?

The reason is to prevent the default action of submitting the form contents to the `action` target. So, we are preventing it from doing it, by returning a false value, which stops the propagation. And, before that, we are making our JavaScript call so that it does our work and not the default one. :)

Comment: Thanks for your explaination. But could you tell me why we need to do like this?

Comment: The reason is to prevent the default action of submitting the form contents to the `action` target. So, we are preventing it from doing it, by returning a false value, which stops the propagation. And, before that, we are making our JavaScript call so that it does our work and not the default one. :)

Answer (score 0):

Can you please tell when you want to return false?

As far as i understood is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function validateData(){
    var flag=0;
    //Your validation logic here
    //If validation is not proper then flag=1; else flag=0;
    if(document.getElementById("text1").value==""){
        flag=1;
    }

    if(flag==1){
        return false;
    } else {
        $.ajax({
            success: function(data){

            }
        });
    }
}
</script>

<form name="abc" id="abc" onsubmit="javascript:return validateData()">
    <input type="text" name="text1" id="text1"/>
    <input type="submit" name="sub"/>
</form>
```